# C# Winform Execute command line requiring a second input

Tags: c#, windows

I used below code to execute a command line, calling to another application for example.

```
string strCmdText = @"gpg --recipient foo@mail.com --encrypt file-name.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

I called it from windows service. It didn't throw any exception but not working also. If I open cmd and execute the command above manually, it will ask me to answer a yes/no question before executing the command. So my question is how to answer that yes/no question programmatically.

Comment: Be specific & add the yes/no question.

Comment: What you're wanting to do is interact with a process you started. To do this, you need to redirect the standard input and output stream. Try searching on that. Or just what @rene said...

Comment: try `-yes` as an extra argument *Assume "yes" on most questions.* https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html

Comment: `Start` returns a [Process(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) object with the process you just started. Store it on a variable and use its StandarOutput, StandardInput properties to read any prompts and write any responses

Comment: There is no point in starting cmd.exe, you might as well start gpg directly.  But if want to use cmd.exe then you have the use the /c option to tell it to execute the command provided on the command line and exit afterwards.  So it must be string strCmdText = @"/c gpg etcetera";  Use /k at first so you can see any error messages.